# GCHandle Allocation in C++/CLI Application with .NET6 causing memory of variable to be corrupted (overwritten)

Tags: windows, c++-cli, .net-6.0

I have an application which is using an native library (via a C++/CLI Wrapper). I updated this application to .NET6 and suddenly it was behaving strange. I narrowed it down to a rather simple looking piece of code.

To reproduce I created a simple solution, containing a .NET6 console project and a C++/CLI project (using .NET6 and the toolset v142). Both with a single file.

During the call to `GCHandle::Alloc()` the memory of the variable `UnexpectedValueChange` gets overwritten (it changes from false to true).

Console project (used to start the application)

```
using wrapper_namespace;

public class Application
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var wrapper = new Wrapper();
      wrapper.CallToWrapper();
   }
}
```

C++/CLI project

```
#include <iostream>

namespace wrapper_namespace
{
    bool UnexpectedValueChange = false;
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle Handle;
    delegate void ConverterProgressCallbackDelegate(double progress, int phase);

    public ref class Wrapper
    {
    public:

        static void CallbackFunction(double d, int i)
        {
            return;
        }

        void CallToWrapper()
        {
            auto callback = gcnew ConverterProgressCallbackDelegate(CallbackFunction);
            SetRestoreProgressCallback(callback);
        }

        void SetRestoreProgressCallback(ConverterProgressCallbackDelegate^ progressCallBackFunction)
        {
            std::cout << "Value of bool before alloc: " << UnexpectedValueChange << std::endl;
            Handle = System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::Alloc(progressCallBackFunction);
            std::cout << "Value of bool after alloc: " << UnexpectedValueChange << std::endl;
        }
    };
}
```

During the allocation in the method "SetRestoreProgressCallback" in the wrapper, the value of the boolean "UnexpectedValueChange" changes to true.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how to fix this issue?

**Update**

Moving the GCHandle inside the class seems to work. In addition the debugger output for the GCHandle outside the class looks strange (it seems like the debugger doesn't recognize the Handle? - it shows "Unable to resolve identifier: 'GlobalHandle'").

Any idea why?

```
namespace wrapper_namespace
{
    System::Boolean UnexpectedValueChange = false;
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle GlobalHandle;

    public ref class Wrapper
    {
    private:
        System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle ClassHandle;
    public:
       void CallToWrapper()
        {
            SetRestoreProgressCallback();
        }

        void SetRestoreProgressCallback()
        {
          // with ClassHandle bool stays false as expected
            std::cout << "Value of bool before alloc: " << UnexpectedValueChange << std::endl;
            auto dummy = gcnew System::String("test");
            ClassHandle = System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::Alloc(dummy);
            std::cout << "Value of bool after alloc: " << UnexpectedValueChange << std::endl;
            ClassHandle.Free();

          // with GlobalHandle bool gets modified
            std::cout << "Value of bool before alloc: " << UnexpectedValueChange << std::endl;
            auto dummy2 = gcnew System::String("test");
            GlobalHandle = System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle::Alloc(dummy2);
            std::cout << "Value of bool after alloc: " << UnexpectedValueChange << std::endl;
            GlobalHandle.Free();
        }
    };
}
```